# Javascript .html() returns html with tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

In my ROR application,

in my controller

1 - `@linkhtml="Please contact #{ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to 'support', "www.blahblah.com"}."`

which calls a js file, create.js, in that..

2 - `$(#linkhtml).html('<%= @linkhtml %>')`

and in erb file

3 - `<div id=linkhtml></div>`

returns

`<a href="www.blahblah.com/">support</a>`

How do I make it return a linked 'Support'?

EDIT:

I should either use strip_tags in 1
or use something() instead of html() in 2
or display it someother way instead of 'id=linkhtml' inside the div in 3

Comment: then `$('#linkhtml').html('<%= @linkhtml %>')` should have worked

Answer (score 0):

```
$(#linkhtml).text()
```

This will return the plain text without the HTML tags

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/text/